# PHP exec progress bar

Tags: php, exec

How can i create a progress bar that show the percentage of the download in my php script ?

```
if($_POST['submitbtn']){
    $user = $_POST['usuario'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $download = "wget -P /var/www/html/$user/downloads $url";
     exec($download);
```

Is it posible ?
thank-you!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use cURL built into PHP?  Also, you have effectively let anyone execute whatever they want on your system by not escaping paths.  You're also allowing folks to install whatever scripts they want on your server.  This whole thing is a security nightmare.

Comment: i did not thought about that, i will use cURL, but i still need a progress bar for it...

Comment: And for that, you will need a script running in the background, updating the progress of the download in a database or something.  One script to do the download and update the DB, another script to return the progress info over AJAX to your front page.

Comment: the first one is already done, its updating the db and making the download. i will do the background now. Thank-you for your help Brad.